# SVG elements CSS transition inside <g> tag on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, transition, fill

So I've created a page with some colorful SVG images in it, and I want them to be grayed at hormal state, and shows color while hovered.

```css
    svg {
        width: 200px;
        margin: 50px;
    }

    svg * {
        transition: fill 1s;
    }

    svg:not(:hover) * {
        fill: gray !important;
    }
```

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 3 1">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" style="fill: red" />
        <rect x="1" y="0" width="1" height="1" style="fill: green" />
        <rect x="2" y="0" width="1" height="1" style="fill: blue" />
    </svg>

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 3 1">
        <g>
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" style="fill: red" />
            <rect x="1" y="0" width="1" height="1" style="fill: green" />
            <rect x="2" y="0" width="1" height="1" style="fill: blue" />
        </g>
    </svg>
```

As one can see, SVGs have different colored elements, also some elements are grouped. This is pretty simplified example, but the real images are much more complex, with massive `transform`-s so I can't easily remove grouping.

Both images work perfect and changes colors while hovered, but the first image does it instantly while the the second has 1 second delay before animation starts.

Searching for the solution I've found that if an elemend is wrapped with a single `<g>` tag it has the animation delay, but if there no `<g>` or **two** of them, no delay occurs.

Firefox animates both images with no animation delay.

By the moment I ungrouped elements by hands, but obviously it's not a good solution, so the question is how it can be solved without changing files at all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pretty sneaky bug, but easily solved: just restrict the child selector to non-`g` elements:

```css
    svg {
        width: 200px;
        margin: 50px;
    }

    svg :not(g) {
        transition: fill 1s;
    }

    svg:not(:hover) * {
        fill: gray !important;
    }
```

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 3 1">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" style="fill: red" />
        <rect x="1" y="0" width="1" height="1" style="fill: green" />
        <rect x="2" y="0" width="1" height="1" style="fill: blue" />
    </svg>

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 3 1">
        <g>
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" style="fill: red" />
            <rect x="1" y="0" width="1" height="1" style="fill: green" />
            <rect x="2" y="0" width="1" height="1" style="fill: blue" />
        </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, although looks as weird as the problem itself.